# How to properly use dockcross for cross-compilation?

Tags: c++11, docker, cmake, compilation, cross-compiling

**Some Background**

I am trying to cross-compile an app I have for RaspberryPi 3B. I have installed [dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross) as below:

```
docker run --rm dockcross/linux-armv6 > ./dockcross
chmod +x ./dockcross
mv ./dockcross ~/bin/
```

On my host, macOS high sierra, I can compile and link without a problem.

**Issue**

First I run: `dockcross cmake -Bbuild -H.`. After that running `dockcross make`, naturally, compiler gives an error: `<some-lib/some-lib.h> not found`.

After this I accessed the container bash by `dockcross bash` and installed all missing libs and their headers to container. Unfortunately, error is same and compiler can't find headers. Contents of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (myLibProject)

include_directories(
    .
    /usr/include
)

link_directories(
    /usr/lib
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

file(GLOB SOURCES
    "include/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_library(myLibProject ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(myLibProject some-lib)
```

When dry-run make - `make -n` - I can't see the include directive for folders other than current - `.` - folder :

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++   -I/work/.  -std=c++11   -o CMakeFiles/myLibProject.dir/src/src1.cpp.o -c /work/src/src1.cpp
```

If I manually run the above command by adding `-I/usr/include`, compiler successfully compiles src1.cpp.o

**Questions**

1. Why CMake haven't picked-up other directories? They are present at container linux.
2. My project have a lot of dependencies, for example boost. How should I modify my `CMakeLists.txt` to properly compile my projects using dockcross?

Comment: It seems that CMake simply drops `/usr/include` directory from include directories list, as described in this bugreport: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17966. However, I find it strange that you use *host* include directory - `/usr/include` (and even host libraries) for *cross-compiling*. Usually, cross-compiling uses libraries which are compiled for the target platform and installed under a sysroot. BTW, even the [toolchain file](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/blob/master/linux-armv6/Toolchain.cmake) for your platform implies, that host libraries are not searched.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, how should I modify so headers and lib are searched in container when using dockcross?

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with dockcross, so cannot point to a proper way. I just pointed that your current way *looks* wrong. This conclusion is based on my experience and the toolchain file which content I understand. However, I may be wrong. Suggestion (my *guess*): you may navigate into sysroot, specified in the toolchain file (it refers to the value of environment variable `CROSS_ROOT`). Probably, content of this directory gives you some hints.